# JS Date Object setUTCMonth() increase months by two?

Tags: javascript, date

I have very weird situation where I am setting UTC month value for an date object using `setUTCMonth()` method. But it is getting increased by two.

My written code outputs on console start and end day of months.

```js
// user input 

var start_month = 1;
var start_year = 2013;

var end_month = 6;
var end_year = 2013;

// code

start_month = start_month - 1;
end_month = end_month - 1;

var start_date = new Date();
start_date.setFullYear(start_year);
start_date.setUTCMonth(start_month);

var end_date = new Date(end_year, end_month);
end_date.setFullYear(end_year);
end_date.setUTCMonth(end_month);

console.log('<< START >>');
start_end_log(start_date, end_date);

function start_end_log(start_date, end_date){
    
     if(start_date.getFullYear() == end_date.getFullYear() 
        && start_date.getUTCMonth() == end_date.getUTCMonth()
       ){
         console.log('<< THE END >>');
         return;
     }
    
    start_date.setUTCDate(1); // go back to frist day of the month
    var start_date_str = start_date.toISOString().substr(0, 10); // get first day
    start_date.setUTCMonth(start_date.getUTCMonth() + 1); // increase to next month
    start_date.setUTCDate(0); // go back to last day of last month
    var end_date_str  = start_date.toISOString().substr(0, 10); // get last day

    console.log('start date: ' + start_date_str + ' End date: ' + end_date_str);
    
    var month = start_date.getUTCMonth();
    console.log('current month ' + month);
    
    month++;
    console.log('after increment month ' + month);
    
    start_date.setUTCMonth(month); // go to next month
    console.log('Check after setting month ' + start_date.getUTCMonth()); // why it is increasing by 2? :(
    
    start_end_log(start_date, end_date);
    
}
```

JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jhg7ddjh/

I am outputting the month number just after setting it on console. I do not understand how it get increased by two.

### Solved

Before calling `getUTCMonth()` the date needed to set back to a date that is available for next month.

**Changed**

```
start_date.setUTCMonth(month); // go to next month
```

**to**

```
start_date.setUTCDate(1);
start_date.setUTCMonth(month); // go to next month
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
start_date.setUTCDate(0);  // go back to last day of last month
```

...means `start_date` will be on the last day of a month. In your example, that month is January, which has 31 days, so now `start_date` is on `31/01/2015` (despite `start_date_str` being `"01/01/2015"`, and since you use `start_date_str`, not `start_date`, in your `console.log` statement, it's fairly confusing to read the output).

Then you do

```
var month = start_date.getUTCMonth();
console.log('current month ' + month);

month++;
console.log('after increment month ' + month);
```

...which sets the month to 1 (February) on a date with a day value of 31, giving you (in theory) `31/02/2015` — you see the problem, there aren't 31 days in February.

JavaScript dates are smart, and so it adjusts that to `03/03/2015` (March, month #2), and so when you call `getUTCMonth`, you get back 2, not 1.

Comment: Spot on! I had to set the date back to 1st day of the month. Thanks!